# In my Project (Random quote generator). I am unable to sort issue?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fetch-api, dom-manipulation

I am making Random quote machine project using vanilla javaScript. I am doing this project using fetch-api(quotable.io) and simple Dom manipulation. My code is correct but there is some issues that I am unable to identify.

My Code is:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Random.css">
    <title>Random Quotes Machines</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Random Quotes </h1>
    <br> <br>
    <div class="container">
<p class="p">undefined </p>
<h6 class="author"> undefined</h6>
    </div>
    <button class="NextQuote" onclick="NextQuote()">NextQuote</button>
    <!-- <button class="previous">Previous</button> -->
    <script>

let container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
let p = document.querySelector(".p");
let author = document.querySelector(".author");
let rem;
function NextQuote (){
rem = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
 fetch('https://api.quotable.io/random')
 .then(response => response.json())
  .then(quotes => {
    p.innerHtml = '"${quotes.content}"';
   
  }  
    );
}

    

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the expected result and the actual result and are there any error messages? .

Comment: actullay ! Their is no output is showing. You can check my codehttps://codepen.io/Zain-ul-abedin-Zubair/pen/porWQQg

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `innerHtml` to `innerHTML`.

And you need to change `'"${quotes.content}"'` to `quotes.content`.

The result would be:

```
fetch('https://api.quotable.io/random')
 .then(response => response.json())
  .then(quotes => {
    p.innerHTML = quotes.content;
      }  
    );
```

Comment: yes! It's working thank you salah-chaouch.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample almost works. There are only some small issues in your code:

1. `quotes.content` contains a plain text, to add the text to the paragraph you could use `p.textContent` instead.
2. you are using simple quotes instead of backticks for the template string, so your variable `quotes.content` wouldn't be interpolated.

To make it work replace the line `p.innerHtml = '"${quotes.content}"';` with `` p.textContent = `"${quotes.content}"`; ``